# What is going on in a sprain and how do sprains heal?

Tags: self-healing-repairing, sprain-strain-twist

What exactly is a [sprain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprain) and how do they heal?
How can we make them heal faster?

Google has only sent me links to dealing with injuries not understanding how they heal.

The distinction between a [strain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_(injury)) and a sprain seems to be whether is a tendon, muscle or ligament but in the case of something like a finger it is perhaps not always easy to tell which is affected.

Context:

A long time ago I fell and sprained my wrist. It felt quite obviously like I'd overstretch a tendon, muscle or ligament.

More recently I fell and sprained a couple of fingers. This feels different. The joints are swollen. Its sometimes painful to touch even a couple of weeks later and my range of motion is reduced. I can't touch the top of my hand with my middle two fingers yet. Nothing is obviously broken or misaligned.

I'd like to understand what goes on in this kinds of injury and how the body repairs itself.

I did not immobilize my fingers with a brace/splint at the time. Perhaps I should have?
I've been using an anti-inflamatry ointment (voltarol = diclofenac diethylammonium) on it and occasionally a compression bandage

A joints reaction to this kind of injury is to become inflamed to protect itself. So why do we want to reduce inflamation? How does this improve on whatever healing mechanism evolution we have evolved?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the[reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.